# going through all values in nested dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning nested dictionary in Python. I need to find the average expenditure for each financial year between 1997-98 and 2011-12 and then I need to list them in chronological order by financial year with format xxxx-xx only if the average is greater than zero. And then my result should look like i.e. 1997-98 (100,000,000).The average has no decimal i.e. 100,000,000.10.

My questions are:

1. how can I go through all the financial years since my output shows only one result
2. how can I put comma(,) between digits?
3. how can I order them chronologically?

   ```
   for k,v in cleaned_data.items():
       #iterate through all the record 
       fin_year = v["fin_year"]

       if fin_year and v["expenditure"] :
           year = fin_year.split("-")

           if int(year[0]) >= 1997 and int(year[0]) <= 2011:
               total += int(v['expenditure'])
               count += 1 
   if count != 0:
       average = (total/count)
       if average != 0:
           print("Average health expenditure")
           print ('{} ({})'.format(fin_year, average*100000))                 
   else:
       pass
   ```

Cleaned_data is the following:

```
{'1':
{'fin_year': '1997-98','expenditure': '315'},
'2':
{'fin_year': None,'expenditure': '120'},
'3':
{'fin_year': '2000-01', 'expenditure': '314'},
'4':
{'fin_year': None, 'expenditure': None},
'5':
{'fin_year': '1997-98', 'expenditure': '12'}
}
```

enter code here

Comment: is cleaned_data nested dictionary?

Comment: yes it is nested dictionary

Comment: can you write cleaned_data simple in your post?

Comment: I posted the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use below code:

```
goal_years = list(range(1997, 2012))

result = dict()

for year in goal_years:

    total, count = 0, 0

    for k, v in cleaned_data.items():

        if v["fin_year"] and v["expenditure"]:

            if int(v["fin_year"].split("-")[0]) == year:

                total += int(v["expenditure"])

                count += 1

    if count:

        result['{}-{}'.format(year, str(year + 1)[-2:])] = total / count * 100000

if result:

    for k, v in result.items():

        print(k , "{:,}".format(int(v)))
```

below code set comma between digits:

```
"{:,}".format(<number>)
```

I help it helps you